# I don't know how to add a delete button to Lightning-datatable

Tags: salesforce, apex, lwc

Here is my Lightning-datatable:

[image]

Tell me how to make Delete buttons (in the Action column) and how to delete the line on this button when you click on the Delete button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

```
<lightning-datatable
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
    key-field="id"
    actions={[
        { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' }
    ]}
    onrowaction={handleRowAction}
></lightning-datatable>
```

When the action is triggered on a row in the table, the `onrowaction` event will be fired, and the event handler specified by the `onrowaction` attribute (in this case, `handleRowAction`) will be called.

In your event handler:

```
function handleRowAction(event) {
    const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
    const row = event.detail.row;
    switch (actionName) {
        case 'delete':
            deleteRecord(row);
            break;
        default:
    }
}

function deleteRecord(row) {
    // Implement logic to delete the record associated with the row
}
```